# How to Call a Rest Web Service by Asp.net MVC 4 Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How do I call a external Rest Web Service by Asp.net MVC 4 Web Api to repackage the json and send the info to the view so that it can by parsed using Angularjs?

Comment: What is the problem? are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yes.  Getting this  500 Internal Server Error
HeadersResponseJSONCookies

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an
 object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at TestMVC.Controllers.CustomerReportController
.Get() in C:\\Users\\YYY1C75\\Desktop\\TestMVC changes 1-12-16\\TestMVC\\TestMVC\\Controllers\\CustomerReportController
.cs:line 33\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers

Comment: Did that make sense?  Any help

Comment: do you get this error on your side, or in the external webservice? If it is yours, on what line the exception is throw?

Comment: Getting this on my side.  How do I call external web service using webapi

Comment: I think you need to do a little more digging.  If you set a breakpoint and debug, you can find the exact line number where the error occurs and inspect the variables.